# Question about Mongoose Nodejs UPDATE AND GET data delay

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I recently encounter a problem that is regarding to the CRUD development process. When I update a property and send the response to the postman, postman always display the previous data. For example, after I clicked send on Postman, it displays "weeks" : "11" instead of "10". ==>[First Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0mEp.png)

Then when I click the send button the second times, it updates the postman display "week" : "10" instead. ===> [Second Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yidQ.png)
 Have anyone encounter this problem before? What is the best solution?

Here is the link to the code related to my questions: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-tdd-c9rej

I just don't know if this only happens to postman or it does happen to all the final production as well.

Comment: I basically just copy a portion of my code which contains update feature here in the code sandbox. Please take a look and let me know if there is anything wrong: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-tdd-c9rej

Comment: I have it on the Code Sand box. Because there are so many files attach to the update method, that's why I can't paste it to here. Even if I did, it will be really hard to read. Don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer you real quick. You just need to add some options to the query.

You should set the new option to true to return the document after update was applied.

[https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html#:~:text=As%20the%20name%20implies%2C%20findOneAndUpdate,was%20before%20update%20was%20applied.&text=You%20should%20set%20the%20new,document%20after%20update%20was%20applied](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html#:%7E:text=As%20the%20name%20implies%2C%20findOneAndUpdate,was%20before%20update%20was%20applied.&text=You%20should%20set%20the%20new,document%20after%20update%20was%20applied).

```
exports.unblockUser = withCatchErrAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { userId } = req.params;

  // **blocked** is set to hidden by default, now we explicitly turn that back on
  const doc = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    userId,
    { blocked: false },

 // The key Code is here
    {
      new: true,
      runValidators: true,
    }
  ).select("+blocked");

  if (!doc) {
    return next(new OperationalErr("User ID does not match any user"), 400);
  }

  return res.status(200).json({
    status: "success",
    data: {
      user: doc,
    },
  });
});
```